# How can I connect domain to aws whm

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm

I have a domain bought from GoDaddy. I have set the custom name servers this

```
ns1.domain.com
ns2.domain.com
```

and set hostname

```
ns1  52.70.xxx.xxx(aws ip)
ns2  52.70.xxx.xxx (aws ip)
```

As I have installed WHM in my amazon aws instance. so In WHM, I have created an account and then went to Edit DNS Zone and added A records. These are my settings there

[image]

But I don't see my domain working and I am not able to see Cpanel of the domain as well.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow these steps to integrate your domain into whm and create a cpanel.

Create an account in WHM by going into **Account Functions->Create Account**: enter your domain here

Go to **DNS Functions->Edit Dns Zone** and click your domain and add A records

Then Go to Godaddy or any Company where you have purchased your domain and edit the name servers. For example if the nameservers you set in whm dns were **ns1** and **ns2** then same add here(e.g godaddy). In your case it would be

```
ns1.domain.com
ns2.domain.com
```

Click Manage hostname in Godaddy and add

```
ns1  52.70.xxx.xxx(aws ip)
ns2  52.70.xxx.xxx (aws ip)
```

Your domain should be working here. But If still It didn't work then 
Check if ports(2087,2083,53,2095) are open. Check it from the terminal

```
nmap -Pn -sT 172.31.iphere --reason -p 2087,2083,2095,53
```

If any port is closed. Open it from the aws by going into Security Firewall.

Please note, 2083 and 2095 will always show as closed from external port scans as these ports are only opened publicly based on valid sessions established from within the cPanel server.

Verify again if your DNS port is opened

```
nmap -Pn -sT 172.31.iphere --reason -sU -p 53
```

After opening all the ports rebuilt your DNS configuration on the server by typing these commands on the terminal

```
 cpanel root@9449099 /var/named]cPs# cd /etc
 cpanel root@9449099 /etc]cPs# mkdir /root/cptechs
 cpanel root@9449099 /etc]cPs# mv named.conf /root/cptechs
 cpanel root@9449099 /etc]cPs# mv rndc.* /root/cptechs
 cpanel root@9449099 /etc]cPs# /scripts/rebuilddnsconfig
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Nameservers for domain.com that are ns1/2.domain.com?

If this is the case the domain will not be able to resolve without adding the ns1/2. as "Child Nameservers".

You can create that for your domain through GoDaddy https://uk.godaddy.com/help/add-my-own-host-names-as-nameservers-12320

Alternatively - you can post your domain so we can troubleshoot it if it's a DNS issue.